# Extracting and using information from other rows in a dataframe?

Tags: r

So I have a data frame like the following:

```
id age  friend1 friend2
01  15   02      05    
02  23   01      05    
03  51   04            
04  41   03            
05  33   01      02
```

How can I calculate the average age of the friends and create a new column that stores this information? So ideally it looks something like this:

```
id age  friend1 friend2 AvgAgeF
01  15   02      05        28
02  23   01      05        24
03  51   04                41
04  41   03                51
05  33   01      02        19
```

Currently I can run the following code to do this:

```
inx <- grep("friend", names(dat))
tmp <- sapply(inx, function(i) dat$age[dat[[i]]])
dat$AvgAgeF <- rowMeans(tmp, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, when the "id" for the people aren't in order or aren't numbers at all such as in the following example:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
id    age  friend1 friend2
Bob   15   Jack    Sam    
Jack  23   Sam     Bob   
Sam   51   Bob     Jack     
Sara  41   Henry   NA       
Henry 33   Sara    NA                   
", header = TRUE)
```

The code appears to process incorrectly resulting in the following table (All but Sam's AvgAgeF is incorrect in this case):

```
     id age friend1 friend2 AvgAgeF
1   Bob  15    Jack     Sam      51
2  Jack  23     Sam     Bob      28
3   Sam  51     Bob    Jack      19
4  Sara  41   Henry    <NA>      23
5 Henry  33    Sara    <NA>      33
```

How can I solve for this without changing the Names into numerical ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset column `age` with `friend1` and `friend2` as indices, then `cbind` the resulting vectors. It's now a simple call to `rowMeans`.

```
tmp <- with(dat, cbind(age[friend1], age[friend2]))
dat$AvgAgeF <- rowMeans(tmp, na.rm = TRUE)
rm(tmp)

dat
#  id age friend1 friend2 AvgAgeF
#1  1  15       2       5      28
#2  2  23       1       5      24
#3  3  51       4      NA      41
#4  4  41       3      NA      51
#5  5  33       1       2      19
```

**Edit.**

If there are an indeterminate number of `friend*` columns, another strategy must be followed.
First a dataset, starting with the question data.

```
set.seed(1234)

tmp <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 20, TRUE), nrow = 5)
colnames(tmp) <- paste0("friend", 3:6)
dat <- cbind(dat, tmp)
```

Now, use `grep` to get the `friend` columns.

```
inx <- grep("friend", names(dat))
tmp <- sapply(inx, function(i) dat$age[dat[[i]]])
dat$AvgAgeF <- rowMeans(tmp, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Final cleanup.

```
rm(tmp)
```

**Edit 2 - `id` are character strings.**

If the columns `id` and `friend*` are character strings instead of numeric, index column `age` with `match`.

```
inx <- grep("friend", names(dat2))
tmp <- sapply(inx, function(i) {
  x <- as.character(dat2[[i]])
  y <- as.character(dat2$id)
  dat2$age[match(x, y)]
  })
dat2$AvgAgeF <- rowMeans(tmp, na.rm = TRUE)
rm(tmp)

dat2
#     id age friend1 friend2 AvgAgeF
#1   Bob  15    Jack     Sam      37
#2  Jack  23     Sam     Bob      33
#3   Sam  51     Bob    Jack      19
#4  Sara  41   Henry    <NA>      33
#5 Henry  33    Sara    <NA>      41
```

**Data.**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
id age  friend1 friend2
01  15   02      05    
02  23   01      05    
03  51   04     NA       
04  41   03     NA       
05  33   01      02                    
", header = TRUE)

dat2 <- read.table(text = "
id    age  friend1 friend2
Bob   15   Jack    Sam    
Jack  23   Sam     Bob   
Sam   51   Bob     Jack     
Sara  41   Henry   NA       
Henry 33   Sara    NA                   
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this if I had, let's say like 20 "friend" columns and I didn't want to do it manually?

Comment: I was using this code and I realized that if the id is numerically " out of place " per say, that it ceases to work properly. The error I got was when I replaced the id 05 with 06 and all instances of it with the id 06. When this happens, the code treats the id as if it is a NA. Is there a way to go around this problem? I realize that I can just convert all the ids so that there isn't this problem but in the data I am handling I cannot do this since the id contains other information.

Comment: @Jack I don't understand, the code only processes the other columns, why is the `id` relevant? Can you edit the question with an example?

Comment: I edited the post. So in this case the id's/identifiers are no longer numerical and when this happens the code doesn't run correctly.